# Flutter command, Installation Issue

Tags: flutter

I installed flutter SDK but when I run where flutter dart command in CMD. then it didn't saw the dart.exe command and also takes time to show response when I run "flutter doctor". so, what should I do now?? anyone..

I try some resources and documents but they are unabe to provide satisfactory answer.

Comment: did you added flutter bin installation location into the environment

Comment: in your terminal, run "flutter --version" or "which flutter" to ensure you correctly installed flutter and added it to your environmental paths. If not, provide more information to answer your question better.